# Adjust Column Formatting in Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, formatting

I'm customizing a WordPress theme for my website, specifically the FAQ section/page. The following code gives me this [Screen shot 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fz6j5sj6aom7g7/Screen%20Shot.png).

```
[row class="row-fluid"]
[col_3 class="demo_col span9"]

[h3]Frequently Asked Questions[/h3]

[faqs]

[/col_3]
[col_3 class="demo_col active span3"]

[h3]Contact Support[/h3]

[row_2 class="row"]
[col_2 class="span2"]

[h5]We are here to help :)[/h5]

[p class="mb_27"]Please make sure that you are not contacting us for support questions. Please   use the button below.[/p]

[row_1 class="row-fluid mb27"]
[col_1 class="span6"]
[icon name="icon-medkit" class="icon-4x"]
[/col_1]
[col_1 class="span6"]
24x7
we are online
[/col_1]
[/row_1]
[button icon="none" size="large" type="inverse" value="START LIVE CHAT"   href="javascript:void(0);"]
[/col_2]

[col_2 class="span1"]

[/col_2]

[/row_2]

[/col_3]

[/row]
```

I want to delete the content for 'Contact Support' in the 3rd column and have the FAQs span the width of the page. Sort of like this [Screen shot 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8pwouwpdxi3qoyd/Screen%20Shots.png) except for the FAQs to take up the whole width so it doesn't look so crammed. I'm not familiar with HTML, and tried many variations of the code above but only to get what looks like Screen Shot 2. I just can't get it use up the whole width. This theme uses Bootstrap if that helps. Is it possible to adjust the given code to get what I desire? If so, can you please revise the code and post an answer? I can provide any additional information by request. Thanks in advance for your time.

Supplemental Information

- The them I'm using is Awesome App. You can see general information about the theme here [App website link](http://themeforest.net/item/awesome-app-responsive-parallax-wordpress-showcase/5151194).
- I found the short code for the faqs section. Here it is [short code link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dny77zlmvyhmo8f/aa_faqs.php).
- I enter my questions separately and they're automatically put into the [faqs] block.

Comment: The documentation for the shortcodes you are using is the key to solving this. What plugin/theme provides these shortcodes?

Comment: It also seems that the code you posted is incomplete. It's missing the block related to the "What kind of apps can..."  and its content.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added supplemental information that may help. It looks like you're right and the answer lie in the faqs short code. Feel free to identify where I need to make the formatting changes. I'll look into myself as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey I found the spans I needed to change in the short codes folder ---> faq.php Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting code for the FAQS section was in the themes file folders. wp-content --> short codes folder --> faq.php. Once in there, I found the spans I needed to adjust to make it fit the way I wanted.